# Android Java MVC structure

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm just starting to work on Android Studio and I need to make a mobile application using the MVC pattern but I have no idea where to start.
I've seen in some place that the activity_layout.xml is the view, the MainActivity is the model and I need to make just a new Controller class but for me it seems sketchy, is that a correct way? On the other hand I've seen that I need 3 classes (Model, View & Controller) and the MainActivity..
I will need to include 2 threads too but I'll concentrate now only on the MVC because it's more important.
I have no idea where to start.. I know that the View is the UI, the Model handles all the calculations and processes and the Controller makes the connection between the two for updates and the rest, but I have no structure to where to start..

Answer (score 0):

You should first design the appearance of the application.
What you need to interact with the user.(in Activity.xml)

In the next step, it is better to associate the appearance of the App with the activity.(activity.java)

Finally you can implement your model. This is usually done with one or more Java or Kotlin classes or ... Java is highly recommended.

Comment: I forgot to mention I already have the app working, but only multi-threading. I have the functions, the UI, start, incrementations, timer, I just have a bad time trying to move it to the MVC pattern. I'm using Java. So for now the app is made only in the MainActivity (all the functions and initialisations) and the UI is in the activity_main.xml ( not activity_layout.xml as I previously mentioned )